# Passing empty array as parameter in Greenplum function

Tags: greenplum

I have this function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_drop_null(anyarray)
    RETURNS anyarray
AS $$
BEGIN
     RETURN array(SELECT x FROM UNNEST($1) x WHERE x IS NOT NULL);
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

I can get a correct behavior with non-empty array:

```sql
asset=# select 1 FROM array_drop_null(ARRAY[1,2,NULL]::int[] ) x WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(x, 1) = 2;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

However, when I pass an empty array or NULL, I got this:

```sql
asset=# select array_drop_null('{}'::int[] )
asset-# ;
ERROR:  plpgsql functions cannot take type anyarray
CONTEXT:  compile of PL/pgSQL function "array_drop_null" near line 0

asset=# SELECT '{}'::INT[];
 int4
------
 {}
(1 row)
```

When I pass a column with `TEXT[]` to the function, it returns `{}` if the column entry is `NULL`.

Another case:

```sql
asset=# select 1 FROM array_drop_null(ARRAY[NULL]::int[] ) x WHERE x IS NULL;
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

It doesn't return `{}`, instead it returns `NULL`.

I am confused about the behavior. Can someone explain what is going on? What is a proper way to pass an empty array or `NULL`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 8.3 is [no longer maintained or supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: This seems to be a restriction (bug?) in your outdated Postgres version. Because it works with the current version: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f3d88d9f555097bf512c7c3dfeaf0923  Did you try a `language sql` function? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53be759fe3d823778e35762024bb035b

Comment: And with a supported version of Postgres you wouldn't even need your own function as you can use `array_remove(..., null)`

Comment: Right, you should upgrade. It works as it should on v12.

Comment: Right .. I forget to mention that I am using greenplum. It is good to know that it works fine in the later release. I think greenplum 6 has newer postgres, although i am not sure if it has the bugfix.

Comment: What is the use case to use anyarray in Greenplum?

Comment: @JonRoberts for my case I just want to use it for a generic function as I don't have array_remove. I am not sure if that answers your question.